# Can't get iso-8859-1 to work for 'umlauts' (Debian / Plesk)

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php, character-encoding, plesk

I think I have configured ISO-8859-1 at all necessary locations, but still, my pages are displaying black '?' instead of German umlauts!
My server runs Plesk 17.8.11 / Debian 8 / Apache 2 / PHP 7.1 (FPM).

```
Plesk > Websites & Domains > mysite.com > PHP Settings:
    Additional configuration directives:
       default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
Plesk > Websites & Domains > mysite.com > Apache & nginx Settings:
    Additional directives for HTTP:
       AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
    Additional directives for HTTPS:
       AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
    Additional nginx directives:
       charset iso-8859-1;

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
    AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:
    default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:
    default_charset = "iso-8859-1"

.htaccess in the root directory of the affected domain contains:
    AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
```

I hope it is okay to reference one of the affected URLs here to allow checking the source and encoding of the page: 
https://www.psychotherapiepraxis.at/gute_therapie.phtml

All page content is saved in .html files, so the pages' html code isn't retrieved from a database.

Any idea what might be the culprit?

Comment: Sorry but why not UTF-8 everywhere?

Comment: because every html page contains 50-150 umlauts (not using the character entity codes like &ouml; , but plain-written umlauts like 'ö'), and there are hundreds of pages..

Comment: Use a script to fix them. Python can do that, transform encoding and fix HTML headers. Or change your browser settings of clients to display content using iso8859_1.

Comment: I'll second the "do everything in UTF-8" comment. Having a different encoding will only cause you pain in the long run. Another option instead of a custom script is `iconv`.

Comment: Another UTF-8 advocate: This is the 21st century: all OSes running nowadays can interpret Unicode: you're using 1990s technology. (Entschuldiging aber äëïöü und auck ÿ sind perfekt möglich mit UTF-8)

Comment: thanks for your feedback - my pages are basically long articles, and I like to be able to read, update and correct them in 'readable' format (including umlauts instead of HTML codes). Is there a way to use umlauts in the text body but still have the page displayed okay if the server 'insists' of delivering UTF-8?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is the basic encoding for Central Europe as is 7-bit ASCII for the US. BTW: the low 256 characters in UNICODE are identical to ISO-8859-1 and if UTF-8 did use a better coding/handling there was a better UTF-8 acceptance. People who belive that UTF-8 does not cause problems usually live in the US and only use the low 128 characters and for that reason de-facto still use 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @richey How do you edit the pages? Do you write html in an editor? If so, there is probably a setting in the editor for it to use UTF-8. Likewise for any other tool, like a content management system or dedicated off-line web page editing program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm frustrated that Plesk - that is meant to support webmasters - doesn't offer a meaningless way to effectively set the encoding of a site's pages, in order to get this to work.

I just batch-converted all of my pages to UTF-8 using this very helpful answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157064/need-to-batch-convert-a-large-quantity-of-text-files-from-ansi-to-unicode and pages display correctly now.